# i am facing below error on my "npm run build" in laravel project its frontend is in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, laravel, npm, vite

i am facing below error on my "npm run build" in laravel project its frontend is in react typescript. on npm run dev is work fine. but when i need to run "npm run build" its giving me below bug. i have this code place in wamp "C:\wamp64\www\test" test is my project folder.
[facing this error on npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDBCz.png)

my tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["common/resources/client/*"],
      "@app/*": ["resources/client/*"]
    },
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["resources/client", "common/resources/client"],
  "exclude": ["*.stories.tsx",
    "bun-server-entry.tsx"
  ],
  "references": [{"path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}]
}
```

my vite.config.ts

```
import {defineConfig, Plugin} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

// override laravel plugin base option (from absolute to relative to html base tag)
function basePath(): Plugin {
  return {
    name: 'test',
    enforce: 'post',
    config: () => {
      return {
        base: '',
      };
    },
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hmr: {
      host: '0.0.0.0',
    },
  },
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
  },
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['puppeteer'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tsconfigPaths(),
    react(),
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/client/main.tsx'],
      ssr: ['resources/client/server-entry.tsx'],
      refresh: false,
    }),
    basePath(),
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      __SENTRY_DEBUG__: false,
      "import { URL } from 'url'": false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

i try to run npm install and check packages path is correct. its only give me error in npm run build not in npm run dev.